# How to check value within 2 random keys inside a firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a string key value which i need to check with a key within the database. if these 2 keys are equal i need to perform certain actions. ive been trying to loop through 2 random keys but it just doesnt work. please help.

```
 dataref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

 @Override
 public void onDeleteClick(int position) {
    Upload selectedItem = mUploads.get(position);
    final String selectedKey = selectedItem.getKey();

    StorageReference imageRef = mStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(selectedItem.getImageUrl());
    imageRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            dataref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        for (DataSnapshot ds2 : ds.child("uploads").getChildren()){
                            String imgkey = (String) ds2.getKey();
                            if (imgkey.equals(selectedKey)){
                                Toast.makeText(ViewSellerProduct.this, "Item Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                int num = (int) ds.child("sold").getValue();
                                ds.child("sold").getRef().setValue(num +1);
                                int num1 = (int) ds.child("points").getValue();
                                ds.child("points").getRef().setValue(num1 + 50);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(ViewSellerProduct.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });
            mDatabaseRef.child(selectedKey).removeValue();
            mmDatabaseRef.child(selectedKey).removeValue();
        }
    });
}
```

my data base:

```
  "Users"
         -RANDOM KEY
                  -address
                  -cty
                  -name
                  -points
                  -sold
                        -uploads
                             -RANDOM KEY
                                    - imgurl
                                    - name
```

Basically I want to increase sold by 1 and points by 50 when the delete is clicked.

Note that I cannot get the current user ID, since the user will be logged in as another account.

OUTPUT OF PRINTING IMGKEY AND SLECTEDKEY:

```
             2019-05-25 23:22:21.279 2450-2450/com.example.re I/System.out: 
             imgkey=-LffFH8AMu_71RFeaHup              
             2019-05-25 23:22:21.280 2450-2450/com.example.re 
             I/System.out: slectedkey = -LfkRLtEiWCyqz51oSY2
             2019-05-25 23:22:21.281 2450-2450/com.example.re I/System.out: 
             imgkey=-LfiHUz4wwrt0IT1tPM4
             2019-05-25 23:22:21.281 2450-2450/com.example.re I/System.out: 
             slectedkey = -LfkRLtEiWCyqz51oSY2
```

Comment: At first glance the code looks fine. But there are definitely thing that we can't see in this code. Can you print `imgkey` and `selectedKey` right before this line `if (imgkey.equals(selectedKey)){`, and then add the output to your question?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen okay im getting those outputs. It seems to be printing twice

Comment: the first imgkeyvalue is from the random key of an upload from the previous user. Fair enough

Comment: I have concluded that it checks/loops through every key before the selectedkey. But for some reason it doesnt check with the last key needed i.e, the selectedkey.

Comment: UPDATE: the if condition starts working from the second time i click delete. Meaning, the 'sold' and 'points' value are incremented respectively. It doesnt seem to happen only on the first delete everytime the app restarts